# Changing MAIL FROM Domain in Amazon AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, email, amazon-ses

I'm using a marketing email application called Mautic to use AWS SES to send emails.  I'm receiving the emails successfully but they're all from the domain `amazonses.com`.  I followed the AWS SES documentation to verify ownership of my domain, I enabled SPF and DKIM successfully, and I put the proper MX records into my GoDaddy DNS.  Everything is 'verified' in the AWS Console, but I'm not sure how to get it to use the "MAIL FROM" domain I've setup.  Mautic has no settings with respect to the "MAIL FROM" domain so I'm pretty sure I'm just missing the last step on the SES in order to get it to actually use the 'from' domain I've setup.

Please let me know if I can provide any more details that might be helpful.  Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Let's clarify: you are *not* using the [Custom MAIL FROM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html) feature, correct?

Comment: Hey @Michael-sqlbot, I'm trying to and I think I've configured all of the steps, but it's not actually "using" it.  I'm wondering what is the "virtual checkbox" that I haven't selected yet that will put everything I did into action.

Comment: So you *are* using it -- or trying to.  What is the current [setup state](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from-states.html)?

Comment: I mentioned this above.  I've completed all of the steps I could find in the SES documentation 'successfully'.  As I said, I'm 'trying' to use it but emails are still coming from the `amazonses.com` domain even though it verified my ownership of the domain I'm trying to send on behalf of.  I am missing whatever the last step is to be able to use the 'MAIL FROM' domain I've setup.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue, but it was because I had verified my email address **before** I set up the MAIL FROM domain. In this case, if you look at the details for the verified email address, you will see the MAIL FROM domain set to **amazonses.com**. It appears that SES uses this value when sending from this email regardless of the MAIL FROM domain setting.

Since my domain is verified, my solution was to simply delete the verified email. Now when I send emails, it uses the domain default which is my MAIL FROM domain setting.

If you are using verified email addresses, check that it shows the MAIL FROM domain that you want to use in the details.

Comment: Can confirm this. And thanks to this answer I only wasted 15 minutes instead of a lot longer as my config was otherwise correct.

Comment: Can confirm this as well. However, I still wanted to have verified e-mails (not only a verified domain). I had to delete **all** verified e-mail addresses connected with the specific domain, make sure the domain has MAIL FROM set up correctly, re-insert the e-mail addresses and validate them.

Comment: Can confirm this too. I had a full domain verified, and an email within that domain verified as well (showing the old MAIL FROM), and the email was taking precedence over the domain. I deleted the email as it was redundant anyway, and everything works now. Thank you!

Comment: As of today, we can change MAIL FROM for verified emails (now called identities) as well. Also, I found that some mail servers disrespect MAIL FROM and use smtp.helo instead which is still amazonses.com, and if case of discrepancy penalize such mails. So, using MAIL FROM in SES makes things actually worse.

Comment: Thanks for this -- confirming that MAIL-FROM was set correctly after I deleted the individually verified email addresses that I'd verified before verifying the domain.

Comment: I added the same custom MAIL FROM to my verified email identity and it started working. Ultimately deleting the email identity made the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out.  In Step 8 of [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim.html) it says "You can now use Amazon SES to send email that is signed using a DKIM signature from any valid address in the verified domain."  I didn't realize I had to have a verified email from this domain under the "Email Addresses" section of the SES console.  I created an email address in my domain, verified it using SES, and now my application can use SES to send email on behalf of my own domain!

Answer (score 0):

AWS also has a Custom Mail From domain setup option.  Here is the doc:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html

Follow the directions very carefully and don't forget you need an SPF record for the new subdomain you create for the Mail From - otherwise SES won't pass it in the header.